# Transit facility at Kuwait Airport

Tags: transit, airport-transfer, kuwait

I'm traveling to Rome from Delhi, India, via Kuwait. What are the options available to spend the transit time (approximately 6 hours) in the airport? I also have a 5-year-old kid with me. Are there some affordable sleeping places? And the entire transit time is at night.

Comment: Have a look at the [airport's Shopping & Relax](https://www.dgca.gov.kw/en/travellers/relax-and-enjoy/airport-hotel) info on its web site.

Answer (score 2):

There are no sleeping places at the current<sup>*</sup> airport, and the air transit hotel that [Mark mentions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/118080/1375) is only accessible to you if you are in transit for more than 8 hours. You also need a special pass and a special bus to take you there, since it is in a high security area.

There are three lounges at the airport: the VIP lounge, the Pearl lounge, and the Emirates lounge.

The Pearl lounge has pay-to-enter facilities. You'll find it just near immigration counters. There are no sleeping areas, but there is a kid-friendly area, decent food, free wifi and comfortable chairs and is a good place to spend some time.

The Emirates lounge is best avoided. It is just a cordoned-off area with poor catering.

The VIP lounge is not accessible to the public.

Other than that, there are no dedicated transit facilities.

The good news is that there are very good catering facilities and the airport is open 24 hours and at night there is relatively little traffic. As the terminal is quite small, you are best advised to try and rest near the food lounge - there is a new area from which some Asian airlines depart, and this will be relatively quiet.

I have previously described the transit experience [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96677/is-transit-visa-required-in-kuwait/97710#97710) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100509/do-i-require-transit-visa-for-kuwait/100534#100534). In summary, it is best avoided until the airport is renovated.

---

<sup>*</sup> 
The airport is going through a major renovation with new terminals and a revamped main terminal. One is dedicated to Kuwait Airways (Terminal 4) and scheduled to open for commercial traffic in August 2018. Jazeera Airways (the local LCC) has its own terminal, called Terminal 5, which is already operational.

There is also the GA terminal (called the Sheikh Saad Terminal) for Flydubai; and finally the *new* airport, called Terminal 2, which is still under construction, will be the main hub.

Answer (score 1):

Easily, the best way to tell is often to go to the airport's website, as indicated in the comments, or to [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/mideast/kuwait.htm) - from this:

- Foreign nationals are not allowed to remain in the airport for more than three hours, and overnight stays are not allowed (this wouldn't include transit)
- there are pay per use airport lounges which might be of use to you
- The Safir hotel is directly accessible from the runway and is for transit passengers.  This might be the easiest option if you wanted some sleep as well.

The airport is also listed as being open 24 hours, so hopefully you'll be able to at least get a coffee.

Comment: Is the hotel considered part of the airport and therefore under the three hour restriction for foreign nationals?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas it's internal, can be used in transit (according to its page)